# How to remove the left and right Padding of a List in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

How to remove the left and right Padding of a List in SwiftUI?
Every List i create has borders to the leading and trailing of a cell.

What modifier should I add to remove this?

Answer (score 256, accepted):

It looks like `.listRowInsets` doesn't work for rows in a `List` that is initialised with `content`.

So this doesn't work:

```
List(items) { item in
    ItemRow(item: item)
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
}
```

But this does:

```
List {
    ForEach(items) { item in
        ItemRow(item: item)
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
    }
}
```

Comment: ForEach with an array of Strings gives me the following error. "Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'"

Comment: I also find applying the .listRowInsets(_) modifier to a Section within a List achieves the desired outcome.

Comment: Much more preferable is the answer listed below `.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())` which causes all the Section and Rows to indent neatly.

Comment: Worth noting that there is also a default minimum height for list items. If your views are smaller than this amount, you will see apparent insets that persist despite these changes. Consider: `.environment( \.defaultMinListRowHeight, 0 )` on the `List`.

Comment: Separators don't match left indentation of content using this approach. They're still where they were before.

Answer (score 172):

Seem we can use `PlainListStyle` for `List` for **iOS 14**

```
List {
    Text("Row")
}
.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
```

Comment: @Marcus because Grouped is pre-defined style for List and it adds insets

Answer (score 58):

There are several spacings that you can change in a list. Take a look at this color-coded map and pick the one that fits your needs:

```
List(1...100, id: \.self) { item in
    Text("\(item)")
        .padding() //  comment to remove PURPLE padding
        .background(Color.yellow)
        // .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets()) //  uncomment to remove BLUE inset
}
// .listStyle(.plain) //  uncomment to remove GREEN inset
// .listStyle(.grouped) //  uncomment to remove RED inset
```

[image: Demo]

<sub>[RTL-Demo Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWO92.png)</sub>

Comment: Great answer! This one explains everything and provides the necessary visual references to the different types of padding that one would want to remove. ✨

Comment: Any idea how to remove ONLY the top green part but not the leading/trailing green parts?

Answer (score 31):

Use this modifier:

```
.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(....))
```

However, as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/3269676-listrowinsets), the insets will be applied to the view **when inside a list**.

> Sets the inset to be applied to the **view** when placed in a list. (emphasis mine)

Using this modifier on the `List` itself will have no effect on the views inside it. You must use the modifier on the **view** inside the `List` for the modifier to have an effect.

Example usage:

```
List {
    Text("test")
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: -20, leading: -20, bottom: -20, trailing: -20))
}
```

Answer (score 20):

The modifier was

```
.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(......))
```

Answer (score 14):

You should call

> .listRowInsets()

for row, like this:

```
List(items) {
            YoursRowView()
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
        }
```

Answer (score 10):

```
.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: look at this answer for better information. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75722515/14180967

Answer (score 10):

## 2022, MacOS

in case of other solutions will not work (and they at the moment does not [for macOS]), you can use the following hack for macOS:

```
List(selection: $selectedItems) {
    // some content
}
// solution
.padding(EdgeInsets(top: -10, leading: -20, bottom: -10, trailing: -20))
.clipShape(Rectangle())
```

Comment: not a good option in 13.4 this needs to be -8 and offsets the scroll bar also :(

Comment: @PeterLapisu can any other options solve this issue?

Answer (score 9):

**Remove paddings**

**iOS 15, Xcode 13**

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack {
        ForEach(viewModel.portfolios) { portfolio in
            PortfolioRow(item: portfolio)
        }
    }
}
```

This gives you complete control over the list (you can also remove separator using this code). Current implementation of List doesn't provide full control and contains some issues.

**Note** that this is a completely different API. Both `List` and `LazyVStack` are lazy containers, but in contrast to `List`, `LazyVStack` doesn't reuse cells, which will SIGNIFICANTLY change the performance when rows are more complex views.

Comment: this destroys the scroll position if the list mutates

Comment: Note that this is a completely different API. Both `List` and `LazyVStack` are lazy containers, but in contrast to `List`, `LazyVStack` doesn't reuse cells, which will SIGNIFICANTLY change the performance when rows are more complex views.

Comment: Another thing to be aware of is that if you use a `ScrollView` instead of a `List` then you can't easily use the swipe to delete and edit mode functionality that the list provides.  You can of course make your own but that's more work.

Answer (score 5):

The above solutions did not solve for me because my List had sections.

This solved for me:

```
List {
    ForEach(years, id:\.self) { year in
        Section(header: SectionHeader(year)) {
            VStack(alignment:.leading) {
                ForEach(cars[year]!, id:\.self) { car in
                    ListItem(car)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width,
                               alignment: .center)
                        .listRowInsets(.init())
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width,
               alignment: .center)
        .listRowInsets(.init())
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

In resume, you have to repeat the command for the section.

Comment: When i select an item, it selects all the rows instead using this code.