# How to remove padding on left and right of list in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am using a List to dynamically create multiple instances of a view, however, when using list padding is added to the left and right of the child views and I can't remove it. I've tried using .listRowInset, but that has yielded no visible effect.

I have created a PostView that works as desired. I am using a 'PostsView' to dynamically generate multiple PostView instances.

The am trying to get the image in the PostView to touch the edges of the screen within the PostsView.

**PostView**

```
import SwiftUI



struct PostView: View {
    var post: Post

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(post.songInfo.album).font(.title)
                Spacer()
                Text(post.songInfo.artist)
            }.padding()

            Image(post.songInfo.albumArtUrl)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(UIImage(named: "sweetner")!.size,  contentMode: .fit)
            HStack {
                Image("plus-icon")
                Spacer()
                Image("comment-icon")
                Spacer()
                Image("headset-icon")
            }.padding()

            HStack {
                Text(post.user.userName)
                Spacer()
                Text(post.textContent)
            }.padding()


        }
    }
}
```

**PostsView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct PostsView: View {
   @ObservedObject var fbVM = FirebaseInfo()

    var body: some View {

       List(fbVM.visiblePosts) { post in
            PostView(post: post)
       }

    }
}

struct PostsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PostsView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the left and right Padding of a List in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56614080/how-to-remove-the-left-and-right-padding-of-a-list-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 15):

**Update**

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58210994/7245977)

> It looks like .listRowInsets doesn't work for rows in a List that is initialised with content

So you can do this if you change your code slightly. First you need to remove the padding from the post view so the text will go to the edge (if that's what you want):

```
struct PostView: View {
  let placeholder = UIImage(named: "arianaGrande")!
  var post: Post

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      HStack {
        Text(post.album).font(.title)
        Spacer()
        Text(post.artist)
      }// .padding() -- This padding adds space before "Sweetener and after Ariana Grande

      Image(uiImage: placeholder)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(placeholder.size,  contentMode: .fit)
      HStack {
        Image("plus-icon")
        Spacer()
        Image("comment-icon")
        Spacer()
        Image("headset-icon")
      }.padding()

      HStack {
        Text(post.username)
        Spacer()
        Text(post.textContent)
      }//.padding() -- Same thing here.
    }
  }
}

struct PostView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    PostView(post: Post(
      artist: "Ariana Grande",
      album: "Sweetener",
      albumArtUrl: "",
      username: "DoesData",
      textContent: "Text Content"
      )
    )
  }
}
```

Then you can initialize your list slightly differently to remove the spacing.

```
struct PostsView: View {
  var posts = [
    Post(
      artist: "Ariana Grande",
      album: "Sweetener",
      albumArtUrl: "",
      username: "DoesData",
      textContent: "Text Content"
    )
  ]

  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(posts) { post in
        PostView(post: post)
          .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
      }
    }
  }
}

struct Post: Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  let artist: String
  let album: String
  let albumArtUrl: String
  let username: String
  let textContent: String
}

struct PostsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    PostsView()
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

**Original Answer**

It looks like you can adjust [padding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list/3270284-padding) on the list itself to remove the leading and trailing margins.

```
import SwiftUI

struct PostsView: View {
   @ObservedObject var fbVM = FirebaseInfo()

    var body: some View {

       List(fbVM.visiblePosts) { post in
            PostView(post: post)
       }.padding(.horizontal, -20) // -20 seems to make it go edge to edge

    }
}

struct PostsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PostsView()
    }
}
```

You also might need to adjust the padding inside `PostView` for the text like this
`Text("Title").font(.title).padding(.leading, -10)` This seems more elaborate than it should be, but it appears to work.

Comment: this is not a proper way on how you should handle dynamic paddings or something that may change

Comment: I agree. I've updated my answer to include a better method.

Comment: It is well know workaround and as far as I know it is the only one that works. Thanks for the update. Upvoting now.

Answer (score 9):

There are several spacings that you can change in a list. Take a look at this color-coded map and pick the one that fits your needs:

```
List(1...100, id: \.self) { item in
    Text("\(item)")
        .padding() //  comment to remove PURPLE padding
        .background(Color.yellow)
        // .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets()) //  uncomment to remove BLUE inset
}
// .listStyle(.plain) //  uncomment to remove GREEN inset
// .listStyle(.grouped) //  uncomment to remove RED inset
```

[image: Demo]

<sub>[RTL-Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWO92.png)</sub>

---

#### Important note:

It looks like `.listRowInsets` doesn't work for rows in a List that is initialized with content. So you need to use `ForEach` inside the `list` like:

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(...) {
            Text("String")
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to have any affect when applied to the view within the list

Comment: [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58210994/7245977) is what you're looking for.