# How to Disable default padding and bounce in List SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

I am creating tableview kind of UI using List in SwiftUI.
I am trying to achieve below things but couldn’t found solution

1. How to remove leading spacing in List (so that row separator will expand full width)?
2. How to disable bouncing effect on scroll?

Thank you for help.

[image]

```
 var names = ["Apple", "Ball", "Cat", "Dog","Egg", "Fox"]
 List(names, id:\.self) {
          Text($0)
      }
```

Comment: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58210994/14351818

Comment: 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58799474/how-to-disable-scrollview-bounce-in-swiftui

Comment: Although for customizing the separator inset maybe try `UITableView.appearance().separatorInset`

Comment: Thank for help but I am not using scrollview or for each or UIKit so above answer is not working for me

Comment: Also with above answer separator is still giving leading space